# How to center a element

Tags: html, css, text-align

How can I apply horizontal align to `<label>` element? If I do this `<label><p>3</p></label>` everything works fine. I don’t understand why `<p>` element has auto margin (centred) when `<label>` is not.

html

```css
body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
  color: white;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: black;
}
.common {
  width: 45%
}
#div1 {
  background: purple;
  text-align: right;
}
#div2 {
  background: orange;
}
#div3 {
  background: olive;
  text-align: right;
}
#div4 {
  background: gray;
}
label {
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="div1" class="common">1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="common">2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="common"><label for="name-label">3</label></div>
  <div id="div4" class="common"><p>4</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please copy the code in your question, do not post code in images

Comment: Please no external links and no screenshots. Use StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: p has default margin, not auto margin

Comment: The external link seams not working 

Comment: Do you want Horizontal alignment or vertical alignment? because you say horizontal but from your code it looks like you're trying to go for vertical

Comment: @asiboe I want to align "3" like "4"

Comment: So that would mean you're looking how to align vertically. I'd suggest working with flex-box. try giving your div `display: flex` and `align-times: center`

Answer (score 2):

By default `p` elements are `display: block` and `label` elements are `display: inline`.

`margin: auto` will centre a block element. It won't centre an inline element.

Use `text-align: center` (and not `right`) on the *parent* of an inline element (the `<div>` in this case) to centre the content within it.

---

The `p` element in your example, is not centred, it is left aligned. If it had `margin: auto` then it would be centred.

---

If you were talking about *vertical* alignment (which isn't what you said) then the `p` element is in the vertical centre, but that is because it has equal top and bottom margins from the user-agent stylesheet **and** its content height combined with the margins make it the **tallest** thing there. If the content in block 3 was taller, then the paragraph would be closer to the top than the bottom of its containing div.

Comment: maybe you can try `flex-flow : row` 


because it can be align on the row

Comment: @Quentin Uhm... why label element won't centre anyway?
`label {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}`

Comment: A block is also, by default, as wide as the space that contains it, so alignment in any direction has no visible effect unless you also change the `width`.